# In "the code", Marcus du Sautoy, tries to explain Chaos Theory

Tags: math, chaos

So at a certain point, he starts with this silly equation

He starts talking about lemmings and how the rate of growth fluctuates and can lead to very unpredictable chaos

Pnext = R * P - R * P * P

simplified to

Pnext = R * P(1-P)

Wich is the same.

where
R is the reproduction rate he says it is less than 2 most of the time
P is the current population
Pnext is the surviving the offspring, I think

so next time around P = P + Pnext

When I saw this I thought; wait a minute

There is no way to ever have a positive number for the next generation. Except if growth or population is negative.

Whatever I tried with this everything went extinct.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: It has nothing to do with programming, It was a pure Math question why did I add math and chaos as tags and post it to the math forum?

Comment: The math forum is math.stackexchange.com Did you mean to post there instead of stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Population `P` is a number between 0 and 1. Think of it as the proportion of the maximum that the ecosystem can support. `P=1` means the entire population dies of starvation the next year because it ate all the food.

Comment: You put me on the track would be willing to aid me further?

Comment: You can post a new question. If it's more about math itself than writing a computer program that uses math, post it to https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: must have made a mistake yesterday. Been rewriting my question with added info from you to the math forum.